# Why is someone else's PC listed in "Network"?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, security

While looking for some files recently in my laptop, I noticed `JOHNDOE-PC` listed under "Network". John Doe happens to be a researcher in a university I am involved with, who I used to interact with relatively frequently about a year ago.

However, I have no idea how this name has shown up in "Network". While I use a "public" university wifi (in the sense that I do not know everyone who uses it), it is only accessible to people with university login credentials. I also have the wifi specified as public when Windows prompted me to select a setting, although I do not remember if I did so before or after my interactions with John Doe. (The latter case seems more likely.)

What could potentially have caused this to show up, and would it potentially be a security risk to me? When I tried to click on `JOHNDOE-PC` to see if I could do anything, I received a message saying:

> **Windows cannot access `\\JOHNDOE-PC`**
>
> Check the spelling of the name. Otherwise there may be a problem with your network. To try to identify and resolve network problems, click diagnose.

So I'm assuming that at the very least, I can't access whatever I might be able to access under "normal" networking conditions on my end.

I should also add that I have pretty much only used WiFi in the past couple years. I am also to be honest not very familiar with networking, internet set-ups, etc.

Comment: There computer is configured to broadcast its existance.  Your computer is configured to discover those devices that are broadcasting their existance.  While the computer is configured to broadcast its existance its not configured to share its files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Network discovery features in windows depend on network locations you pick after you connect to network initially.** This can be changed later in Control Panel -> Network Center (or something similar, I have non-english Windows please correct me if im wrong).

> Choose Public network for networks in public places (such as coffee
>   shops or airports). **This location is designed to keep your computer
>   from being visible to other computers around** you and to help protect
>   your computer from any malicious software from the Internet. HomeGroup
>   is not available on public networks, and network discovery is turned
>   off. You should also choose this option if you're connected directly
>   to the Internet without using a router, or if you have a mobile
>   broadband connection.

source (and other location descriptions: [link to windows.microsoft.com](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/choosing-network-location)

You should use "public" network profile and never disable firewall in networks like this to make sure you are safe.

EDIT / added later:

There are also advanced sharing settings. They define configurations in networks, maybe you changed configuration for public network and now you have public network with discovery and who knows what else turned on.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/what-is-network-discovery#1TC=windows-7

Check also other advanced sharing settings.

Comment: The weird thing is that despite the fact I chose "public network" for this WiFi connection, a bunch of other computers are still visible to me. Should I assume that the owners just haven't chosen the appropriate security settings, and that this isn't a problem on my end?

Comment: These networks are kind of "simplified profiles". Maybe long time ago you turned on network discovery in advanced settings? http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/enable-disable-network-discovery#1TC=windows-7